# Как сделать чтобы курсор не оставлял след за собой в Cosmos OS

Tags: c#, память, ос

У меня есть код в CosmosOS который рисует курсор мыши, но курсор рисует за собой.
Но я не могу понять как сделать курсор единым.

```
private void DrawCursor()
    {
        Pen penCursor = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255));
        Sys.MouseManager.ScreenHeight = 1965;
        Sys.MouseManager.ScreenWidth = 1965;
        uint x = Sys.MouseManager.X;
        uint y = Sys.MouseManager.Y;
        int intX = (int)x;
        int intY = (int)y;
        canvas.DrawPoint(penCursor, intX + 5, intY + 5);
        canvas.DrawPoint(penCursor, intX + 6, intY + 5);
        canvas.DrawPoint(penCursor, intX + 7, intY + 5);

        canvas.DrawPoint(penCursor, intX + 6, intY + 6);
        canvas.DrawPoint(penCursor, intX + 7, intY + 7);
        canvas.DrawPoint(penCursor, intX + 8, intY + 8);

        canvas.DrawPoint(penCursor, intX + 5, intY + 5);
        canvas.DrawPoint(penCursor, intX + 5, intY + 6);
        canvas.DrawPoint(penCursor, intX + 5, intY + 7);
        
    }
```

Пожалуйста помогите;

Comment: Надо наверное запоминать область отрисовки курсора и восстанавливать перед его перемещением.

Comment: Я новичок в Cosmos и я не знаю как это реализовать.

Answer (score 0):

В начало функции добавьте`canvas.Clear(Color.`сюда введите имя цвета заднего фона`)`

Comment: Так курсор вообще не двигается а также другая графика очищается.

Comment: https://github.com/Kayi-KuzinAlexandr25456/MouseSystem, вот ссылка на то, как я сделал курсор мыши. Если что уберёте DrawFilledRectangle();. Но графика все равно будет очищаться. Её надо вызывать ещё в методе DrawCursor()

Comment: Спасибо за ответ